# qooxdoo : how to change project name?

Tags: qooxdoo

How to change qooxdoo project name, e.g. from "projectNameA" to "projectNameB"?

In `generate.py`, following commands are available.

```
>>> Available jobs:
  - api          -- create api doc for the current library
  - api-data     -- create api doc json data files
  - build        -- create build version of current application
  - clean        -- remove local cache and generated .js files (source/build)
  - distclean    -- remove the cache and all generated artefacts of this library
 (source, build, ...)
  - fix          -- normalize whitespace in .js files of the current library (tabs, eol, ...)
  - info         -- collects environment information like the qooxdoo version etc., and prints it out
  - inspector    -- create an inspector instance in the current library
  - lint         -- check the source code of the .js files of the current library
  - migration    -- migrate the .js files of the current library to the current
qooxdoo version
  - pretty       -- pretty-formatting of the source code of the current library
  - profiling    -- includer job, to activate profiling
  - simulation-build     -- create a runner app for simulated interaction tests
  - simulation-run       -- launches simulated interaction tests generated with
simulation-build
  - source       -- create source version of current application
  - source-all   -- create source version of current application, with all class
es
  - source-hybrid        -- create a hybrid application (application classes as
individual files, others catenated)
  - test         -- create a test runner app for unit tests of the current library
  - test-source          -- create a test runner app for unit tests (source version) of the current library
  - translation          -- create .po files for current library
```

but there is no rename project command. Is there a command available to change project name?

Comment: There is an [open bug](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7035) regarding renaming. It describes which steps you have to perform - manually for now :/ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change a project name , e.g. from "projectNameA" to "projectNameB", you only need to find & replace all files in the project folder ( remember to rename all sub-folders ) and issue the command :

**Linux / Mac**

```
./generate.py clean
./generate.py source-all
```

**Windows**

```
generate.py clean
generate.py source-all
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume with "project name" you mean the application's namespace (the "namespace" entry in its Manifest.json). As Richard already mentioned in his comment there are a couple of steps to perform, see the linked [bug](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7035). The actions fall in into one of two categories, renaming files and directories, and changing name references in code. Project files to change are the Manifest.json and config.json. Further modifications have to be made to the `source` tree, particularly beneath `source/class` and `source/resource`. Directories under these paths reflect the application namespace and have to be changed, but mind to only change that many subdirectories as the Manifest.json gives as the namespace. After that you have to change source files in the `source/class` tree, looking for appearances of the old namespace (A global search-and-replace on the *.js files might get you close enough).